# Запросы к базе MySQL с таблицами в 11 и 7 млн значений

Tags: php, mysql, big-data

Выгрузил через API VK данные о пользователях интересующих меня групп. Собственно, две основные таблицы:

1) group2user, пары соответствий "пользователь uid состоит в группе gid", 11 млн значений

2) users, где составлено уникальное множество пользователей без повторений (на основе group2user) и выгруженные полные данные о пользователях - имя, фамилия и так далее

Есть скрипт, написанный на php, который делает следующее: выбирает пользователей из нужной мне страны И выводит список групп для каждого пользователя, в которой состоит каждый пользователь из запрошенной страны. То есть сначала выборка идёт из 11 млн, получаю, предположим, 500-1000 человек из нужной мне страны и потом про каждого ещё данные о том, в каких группах этот пользователь состоит (запрос к 7-миллионной таблице на каждого из этих N человек).

Работает оно крайне медленно. Страница на 500 человек генерировалась минут 15-20-25, сервер с 3Гб оперативной памяти и 2*2Ghz. Как оптимизировать?

```
    mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 
    $sqlzstr  = "SELECT * FROM `users_full` WHERE `lastseen` > 1437217421 AND `country` = " . $_REQUEST['id'];
    //echo $sqlzstr  . ' <br/>';
    $sqlze = mysql_query($sqlzstr,$db)
            or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    // выводим на страницу сайта заголовки HTML-таблицы

    $i = 0;
    // выводим в HTML-таблицу все данные клиентов из таблицы MySQL 
    echo '<body>      <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

      <h1>';

    $cntry = "SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `vkid` = " . $_REQUEST['id'];
    $cntry_sql = mysql_query($cntry,$db);
    while($dataz = mysql_fetch_array($cntry_sql)){ 
        echo $dataz["name"];
    };
    echo '</h1><br/>
    <style>
    span.label-success {
        text-color: white !important;
        color: white !important;
        padding: 2px 4px;
        font: bold !important;
    };
    </style>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Имя</td>
                <td>Город</td>
                <td>Группы</td>
                <td>Статус</td>
            </tr>
    ';

    $ustr = '';
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sqlze)){ 
        $ustr = $ustr . $data['vkid'] . ',';
    };
    $ustr = substr($ustr, 0, strlen($ustr)-1);
    //echo $ustr . '<br/>';

    $users = $vk->api('users.get', array(
        'user_ids'    => $ustr,
        'fields'      => 'online'
    ));
    usleep(340000);

    $sqlzstr  = "SELECT * FROM `users_full` WHERE `lastseen` > 1437217421 AND `country` = " . $_REQUEST['id'];
    //echo $sqlzstr  . ' <br/>';
    $sqlze = mysql_query($sqlzstr,$db)
            or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sqlze)){ 
        $i = $i+1;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `group2user` WHERE `uid` = " . $data['vkid'];
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql);
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            echo '<td>' . $data["first_name"] . '&nbsp;' . '<a href="http://vk.com/id' . $data["vkid"] . '" target="_blank">' . $data["second_name"] . '</a><br/>';

            foreach ($users['response'] as $key => $value) {
                if ($value['uid'] == $data["vkid"]) {
                    if ($value['online'] == 1) {
                        echo '<span  class="label-success">Online</span>';
                    } else {
                        echo 'Заходил(а): '. date('d.m, в H:i', $data["lastseen"]) . ' MSK';
                    };
                };
            };

            echo '</td>';
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            echo '<td>';

            $cityz = "SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `vkid` = " . $data["city"];
            $cityz_sql = mysql_query($cityz,$db);
            while($dataz = mysql_fetch_array($cityz_sql)){ 
                    echo $dataz["name"];
            };
            echo '</td>';

            echo '<td><ul>';
                while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
                    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `groups_full` WHERE `vkid` = " . $data2['gid'];
                    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
                    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
                        echo "<li><a href='http://vk.com/club" . $row3['vkid'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row3['name'] . "</a></li>";
                        flush();
                    };
                };

            echo '</ul></td>';
            echo '<td>
            <select name="status">
<option selected value="1">Не обработан</option>
<option value="2">Отсечка: Не верю м.ж.</option>
<option value="3">Отсечка: Закрыты ЛС</option>
<option value="4">В работе</option>
<option value="5">Отказался</option>
<option value="6">Нет времени</option>
<option value="7">Не живёт в ...</option>
<option value="8">Согласен</option>
<option value="9">Отправил данные</option>
<option value="10">[Другое]</option>
```

Комментарии(0)
    
    ';
    echo '';
    };

Comment: Связь в бд сделана программно или средствами бд?Если средствами бд, то SELECT будет происходить быстрее. Второй момент, настройки mysql на самом сервере, а так же вы ни привели ни чего: 1. ни конфига бд; 2. ни сам запрос; 3. ни конфиг сервера(у вас сервер не понятно какой, сколько кэша у процессора, что за проц, что за ОЗУ)

Comment: Опишите каким образом вы получаете данные. Выбираете пользователей: `SELECT uid FROM users WHERE country = %COUNTRY% LIMIT 500`, потом для каждого из них запрашиваете группы: `SELECT gid FROM group2user WHERE uid = %UID%`? Или как? Опишите этот процесс подробнее

Comment: 11 миллионов строк это совсем не [tag:big-data]

Comment: Здесь куча проблем, не удивительно что все так тормозит. Я бы посоветовал отделить логику от отображения: делаете простой шаблон, который по полученному массиву выводит всю информацию. Проверяете правильность шаблона передав в него созданный ручками массив. Далее, генерируете отдельно данные для шаблона, именно здесь и надо все оптимизировать: получать пользователей, их группы и, возможно, города одним запросом и в цикле формировать исходный массив. Данные из `users_full` так же надо получить только раз, а потом уже использовать то, что получили и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

1. Для таблицы users сделать индекс на страну. Чтобы выборка была не по 11 млн чтений, а по 500-1000.
2. Денормализация данных.

Сделать в таблице **users** колонку **groups** и добавить в неё все идентификаторы групп пользователя. Массив идентификаторов через запятую или массив наименований с использованием XML/JSON-сериализации.

Написать скрипт, который пройдёт по таблице **group2user** и заполнит колонку **users.groups**.

Так исключится основная причина замедления обращение к таблице на 7 млн записей на каждого из 500-1000 пользователей.

3. Горизонтальное маштабирование.

Шардинг на уровне сервера: http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html - разделение таблицы по нескольким серверам.

Разделить таблицы на несколько таблиц можно и на уровне приложения, задав логику вставки в несколько таблиц одинаковой структуры в код. Сервер останется один, таблиц будет несколько.

Записи можно разбивать по частоте обращения на 3-4 группы. Думаю по странам разбивать можно на две группы - Россия и все остальные.

Comment: Или пойти ещё дальше с денормализацией - таблица country2groups. Сделав таблицу выборки групп пользователей по странам. При наличии индекса по названию страны будет одно чтение на всю выборку. Если страна выбирается по числовому коду, то даже индекс делать необязательно.